# Compare contents of two ArrayLists efficiently

Tags: java, arraylist, collections

Any idea why `contains` not working here, these statement always evaluating **false** `firstSchema.contains(firstSchema.get(0))`

```
    List<String> firstSchema = new ArrayList<String>();
    firstSchema.add(0,"test");
    firstSchema.add(1,"testy");

    if(!(firstSchema.contains(firstSchema))){
        System.out.println("hey arraylist content matched");
    }
```

I need to get true if any one or more or all elements from one arraylist matched with other arraylist elements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way to check if a list contains any elements from another list is to call [`contains()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#contains-java.lang.Object-) on one of the lists, passing *each element* as an argument in turn. Something like:

```
public <E> boolean slowListContains(List<E> a, List<E> b) {
  for (E element : a) {
    if (b.contains(element)) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

This is slow, however, because `contains()` is a linear operation (`O(n)`), and since we're calling it in a loop the `slowListContains()` function takes quadratic time (`O(n^2)`) which is poor. We can do better.

A [`Set`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) (or more precisely a hash-based set such as [`HashSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html)) has an efficient `contains()` method which runs in less-than-linear time (constant time in the case of `HashSet`). Converting one or the other list into a `Set` will make the loop in `slowListContains()` much faster. Something like:

```
public <E> boolean fasterListContains(List<E> a, List<E> b) {
  Set<E> aSet = new HashSet<>();
  aSet.addAll(a);
  for (E element : b) {
    if (aSet.contains(b)) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

This isn't perfect, but it's certainly much faster than the naive solution. A slight improvement would be to always convert the smaller list into the `Set`, rather than the first one. You could also take arbitrary `Iterable` parameters rather than `List` parameters, then check if either of them are already a `Set` and if so skip the set-construction step.

Comment: Really appreciate your efforts for explanation Sir :)

Answer (score 2):

Your `if(!(firstSchema.contains(firstSchema)))` loop is wrong. You are trying to find a match in list with itself. You can not check if a list contains itself.
From java doc below is how contains works

```
  Returns <tt>true</tt> if this list contains the specified element.
  More formally, returns <tt>true</tt> if and only if this list contains
  at least one element <tt>e</tt> such that
  <tt>(o==null&nbsp;?&nbsp;e==null&nbsp;:&nbsp;o.equals(e))</tt>.
```

Answer (score 1):

You are checking it incorrectly. See `firstSchema.contains(firstSchema)` is wrong `arrayList.contains(arrayList)` won't work.

Secondly `(firstSchema.contains("test"))` returns `true` as array list does contains `test` and `!` negating the result will not pass `if` statement because `!true = false`.

```
if(firstSchema.contains("test")) {
    System.out.println("Match found !");
}

if(!firstSchema.contains("test")) {
    System.out.println("Match not found !");
}
```

Comment: even `firstSchema.contains("test")` also not working :(

Comment: @Swapnil: I find that very hard to believe. Please post a [mcve] showing that - my guess is that your actual test program has something else going on. (It's also not clear why you're using the overload of `add` that takes an index.)

Comment: @TAsk my bad, Apologies _/\_

Answer (score 1):

If want to check if one list has matching elements , you can do something like this.

```
 List<String> firstSchema = new ArrayList<String>();
firstSchema.add(0,"test");
firstSchema.add(1,"testy");

List<String> testList = new ArrayList<String>(firstSchema);
testList.removeAll(firstSchema);

if(testList.size()<firstSchema.size()){
    System.out.println("some elements match");
}
```

You can also use `retainAll` similarly

Comment: He he it's Nice hack :)

Comment: That's a destructive operation, and it's O(n^2) runtime. Definitely not a good way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is to use Java 8 streams.

```
if(firstList.stream().anyMatch(secondList::contains))
    System.out.println("Content matched");
```

For improved efficiency (if you're working with enough data for it to actually matter) and if possible (unique values), the `secondList` can be turned into a `HashSet`.

Comment: Terminating early doesn't mean it's efficient, it's still quadratic runtime in the general case.

Comment: @dimo414 Yeah, I just realized that the other solutions given aren't *that* bad either. Well, except the `retainAll` one.